# FxFlex Calc sets min-height, while raw value sets max-height

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

```
<div fxFill fxLayout="column">
    <div fxFlex="8" fxLayout="column"> Fixed Header </div>
    <div fxFlex="20" fxLayout="row" [fxHide]="isShow"> Colapsable Header </div>
    <div fxFlex="72" fxLayout="column"> Page content </div>
</div>
```

Like this, if I hide the header, 20% of the page remains blank, cause the div containing the pagecontent occupies still only 72%

But if I use the with calc `<div fxFlex="calc(92% - 20%)">`, this respective div modifies her height depending if the above div is hidden or shown,
so there's never a blank space even if the div gets collapsed..

Why does it work like this ? calc(92% - 20%) its always 72%, so why does it behave differently ?

***More context after editing title of question:***

After observing the generated Html I've gathered that

- `fxFlex="72"` sets a `max-height="72%"`
- `fxFlex="calc(92%-20%)"` sets `min-height="72%"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is because you are using `calc`.

The long answer is that the `fxLayout` library is checking if you are using concrete values(e.g. just a number) or a `calc` function and based on that decides if `min` or `max` height should be applied

```js
    // Fix for issues 277, 534, and 728
    if (basis !== '0%' && basis !== '0px' && basis !== '0.000000001px' && basis !== 'auto') {
      css[min] = isFixed || (isValue && grow) ? basis : null;
      css[max] = isFixed || (!usingCalc && shrink) ? basis : null;
    }
```

snippet form the source that you can find on [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/9618c7bb5b423ed17e9e25f3a6315343a2660d1a/src/lib/flex/flex/flex.ts#L151)

As visible in the snippet the `max-height` won't be applied in the cases where the input has `calc` value.

So now that we have cleared the `calc` case let's dive in the `fxFlex="72"` case.

The `fxFlex` directive/input accepts up to 3 space separated arguments that are as so `fxFlex="{grow} {shrink}" {base}` if only one input is provided like in your case `fxFlex="72"` , this will be evaluated the same way as `fxFlex="1 1 72"`

So now when we go in `if` statement we will check first the result for `css[min]`, in the first half we see `isFixed` property (which will be false, we can skip this one as it's not related to the case).
In the second we have a mix of `(isValue && grow)`, so the `grow` property will be truthy, as it will take a default value of 1.
The more interesting thing here is the `isValue` property, which represent the following logic (again as seen in the source)

```js
   let isValue = (hasCalc || hasUnits);
```

We already discussed the `hasCalc` which will be `false` in this case (as we have the following input `fxFlex="72"` ), about `hasUnits` this is a property that checks if there is any unit beside `%` following the `basis` value (units like %,px,rem...), so in this case the `hasUnits` will also be `false`.

To sum it up we will have `css[min]` value equal to `null`.

Going on the next line we see again `isFixed` value equall to `false` and in the second half of the expression we see the following `(!usingCalc && shrink)` , this time there is no calc function so `!usingCalc` will be `true`, and because we have a default value of `1` for `shrink`, the whole expression will be evaluated as `true` and it will apply the `basis` value as `css[max]`.

If you don't won't to use `calc` i would suggest to do the following

```html
  <div fxFill fxFlex="100" fxLayout="column">
    <div style="background-color: palegreen;" fxFlex="8" fxLayout="column"> Fixed Header <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(179, 24, 174);" fxFlex="20" fxLayout="row" [fxHide]="show"> Colapsable Header </div>
    <div style="background-color: orange;" fxFlex="1 0 72" fxLayout="column"> Page content </div>
  </div>
```

Here instead of `fxFlex="72"` which will have a default `shrink` value of `1`, I'm setting the value to `0` by doing so the `fxLayout` will skip the min-max check that we are looking at right now and will fill the available space.

Comment: Sorry for the late acknowledgment but great answer. Did you did the research after finding the question interesting ? I should have done the same and dig in the source code myself. Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: It was a great and interesting question, at work I'm also using the fxFlex library, so your question was great reason for me to dive into the source for a bit and have a look :)

Comment: Ahh gotcha. I was never great at organising the contents of the page, but with fxFlex I have been doing great. Sorry for missing on giving you the bounty but I went on vacations for some time. Best of luck man!